# Cordova plugin: Equivalent code under windows universal as that for wp8

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins, win-universal-app

I have found a github plugin that does not support windows universal but did run under wp8. I have added a skelton plugin for windows, and it works. But I am at a loss how to proceed in coding the main functionality. 
The plugin takes base64 data and saves it as an image file.
Here is the wp8 original.

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.JSON;

public class Canvas2ImagePlugin : BaseCommand
{
    public Canvas2ImagePlugin()
    {
    }

    public void saveImageDataToLibrary(string jsonArgs)
    {
        try
        {
            var options = JsonHelper.Deserialize<string[]>(jsonArgs);

            string imageData = options[0];
            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);

            using (var imageStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
            {
                imageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                string fileName = String.Format("c2i_{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}", DateTime.Now);
                var library = new MediaLibrary();
                var picture = library.SavePicture(fileName, imageStream);

                if (picture.Name.Contains(fileName))
                {
                    DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, 
                        "Image saved: " + picture.Name));
                }
                else
                {
                    DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, 
                        "Failed to save image: " + picture.Name));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, ex.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

I have been following this set of instructions for Cordova plugins from MS
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn903769.aspx
But it really doesn't discuss how to access the native features of the O/S. How do I access the same features as the wp8 version or does it have to be recoded in C++?